# Converting list to dictionary in Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

```
['monaco:1\n', 'russia:2\n', 'denmark:3\n']
```

into a dictionary in Python 3.3.3, plus any ideas on how to remove the '\n'?

Thanks!

Comment: @wnnmaw Minimal understanding was removed long back from the _off-topic_ list.

Comment: @devnull, I didn't flag as off-topic, but last I check question are still expected to show minimal effort.  That, and answers can be a lot more helpful/instructive if they address broken code or build off of what OP has already done

Comment: @wnnmaw That was a pun.

Comment: @devnull, oh man, this is embarrassing... well played

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> mylist = ['monaco:1\n', 'russia:2\n', 'denmark:3\n']
>>> dict(s.strip().split(':') for s in mylist)
{'denmark': '3', 'russia': '2', 'monaco': '1'}
```

`s.strip().split(':')` takes a string and outputs a list of before and after the colon, with whitespace removed from the ends

Comment: This answer is nearly identical to Martijn Pieters'   But in hindsight, that's rather harsh, sorry :(

Comment: a) i didn't copy his, b) i think it's a lot clearer than using `map`. but no worries, thanks for the explanation

Comment: Agreed, stripping first is better.